# The anatomy of a Play request and response cycle, with all the gory details

Tags: scala, playframework

I was hoping someone could outline the details of a typical play request and response cycle.

Say I have a typical endpoint like:

```
def index = Action {
  Ok("hello, world!")
}

GET  /hello         controllers.home.index
```

So a request comes in, a GET request, and the path is /hello.

How do things work under the covers to eventually return a 200 response OK with "hello, world!" in the response.

If you can link to the actual source code that would be great: https://github.com/playframework/playframework

Answer (score 1):

You will find a good explanation here:

http://www.manning-source.com/books/hilton/PfSch2SAMPLE.pdf

There is no single piece of code to link to. At the moment netty is used to do the heavy lifting and there is a lot of decoration, you could call Play Framework, added around it.